# power supply "compliant standards"?

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking at specifications posted for various PSUs and they have a section labelled "Compliant Standards" and lists things like CE, UL, TUV, C-Tick, BSMI, cUL, CB, CCC, FCC, RoHS.

What do these mean?
Should they influence my decision on which PSU to buy? If so, where can I find more information on what each one means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to say this... but for what each means, Wikipedia is the best place to look.

In general certifications fall into three main types - it's tested to prevent it from catching fire and killing you (for example TÜV - a german test lab and UL - underwriters laboratory), that they meet national specifications (for example CE, or PSB certifications). or they prevent them from poisoning you or the environment (RoHS means the device doesn't have things like lead).

In general, *most* power supplies have to be certified for the country they are sold in, so I'd worry more about power output and efficiency ratings that alphabet soup compliance.

Comment: The first thing I tried was Wikipedia and Google, but those two/three letter acronyms have lots of possible meanings and it's hard to figure out which one I'm looking for.